# Can I access an age-restricted Page's wall feed through the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working on a website for an alcohol brand, and they want to display posts form their Facebook wall on their own website. Naturally they have restricted their Facebook page to 18+, but this means that the wall feed is not publically available, and also not accessible via

http://graph.facebook.com/(page_id)/feed

Is it possible to set up a single, permanent access key to retrieve the feed via the API?

The external website has it's own mechanism for age verification, so we would only be showing the fetched feed to age-verified users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off creating an application on Facebook and use FBML on the site to authorize the 18+ user and then displaying the wall using regular authenicated Graph API calls.